# Email sent from python script is never received

Tags: python, email, smtp

I know this is covered here so many times. I read all the questions but I still can't get it to work.

I'm trying to send an email from a python script:

```
msg= MIMEText('MESSAGE_TEXT')
msg['Subject']= 'SUBJECT'
msg['From']= 'from@example.com'
msg['To']= 'to@example.com'
s= smtplib.SMTP(host='localhost', port=1025)
s.sendmail('from@example.com', ['to@example.com'], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

I am running a local python SMTP server by doing this:

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

When I run the script I get this in the SMTP server:

```
---------- MESSAGE FOLLOWS ----------
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: SUBJECT
From: from@example.com
To: to@example.com
X-Peer: 127.0.0.1

MESSAGE_TEXT

------------ END MESSAGE ------------
```

So it seems that the server is working, but the email is never received (I checked spam folder as well)
I realise that I could use gmail's SMTP server but I really don't want to do that. What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Ask the e-mail server administrator about it. E-mails are usually logged to make them traceable, for this exact reason. This is not a programming question.

Comment: Unfortuantely, I am the email server administrator and I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: As I said, there are usually log files to read. Follow the message through your mail servers. Make sure the message is actually delivered and received by the next server.

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky when you don't know how the server responds.

What I would recommend you to do is connect to the SMTP-server and try and [send the email manually](http://www.wikihow.com/Send-Email-Using-Telnet) using telnet. Since you're using Python, I'm guessing it's a *NIX system. But telnet (as the example uses) works great there as well (or netcat).

This way you get the message in hand and you don't have to guess any more.

Comment: I ended up creating a dummy gmail account and using it out of frustration. I'll look into telnet next time I need to do this. Thanks.